# rails mongodb store time and then use that to query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

```
33] pry(main)> Tweet.last.c_at.to_s
=> "2013-09-30 12:39:25 +0800"
[34] pry(main)> Tweet.last.c_at
=> Mon, 30 Sep 2013 12:39:25 CST +08:00
[35] pry(main)> Tweet.gt(c_at: "2013-09-30 12:39:25 +0800").count
=> 1
[36] pry(main)> Tweet.gt(c_at: "Mon, 30 Sep 2013 12:39:25 CST +08:00").count
=> 0
```

the query it fire up is different

```
command={:count=>"tweets", :query=>{"c_at"=>{"$gt"=>2013-09-30 04:47:33 UTC}}} (0.8490ms)
command={:count=>"tweets", :query=>{"c_at"=>{"$gt"=>2013-09-30 18:47:33 UTC}}} (0.8671ms)
```

why this happen and how to store time and then use that to query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are dealing with datetimes here. this is not a mongodb issue nor a rails issue, it's just the input that is broken:

```
Time.parse "2013-09-30 12:39:25 +0800"
=> 2013-09-30 06:39:25 +0200
Time.parse "Mon, 30 Sep 2013 12:39:25 CST +08:00"
=> 2013-09-30 20:39:25 +0200
```

i assume, that this is due to the CST in the last date string:

```
Time.parse "Mon, 30 Sep 2013 12:39:25 +08:00"
=> 2013-09-30 06:39:25 +0200
```

Comment: thanks, can you provide some way to solve this? I mean store datetime and query use that without shift several hours?

Comment: no, you will have to fix those dates, wherever they are coming from